# Compare numpy 3D array with 2D array aisle by aisle

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, mask

I have large amount of m-by-n 2D arrays that need to be compared with one reference m-by-n 2D array (of course it's not all 1),

```
arrays = np.random.rand(m,n,k)
array_ref = np.ones((m,n))
result = np.zeros_like(arrays, dtype=np.bool_)
for k_id in range(k):
    result[:,:,k_id] = arrays[:,:,k_id]> array_ref
arrays[result] = np.nan
```

Right now it takes 0.4s per 128 comparisons, I'm wondering if there's a direct comparison that can be faster, without using the for-loop? I hope it to be something simplified like `arrays[arrays>array_ref]=np.nan`, but as long as it runs faster it's ok.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use broadcasting! `result = arrays > array_ref[:, :, None]`. More info: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: On a more general note: You could consider storing the batch dimension `k` in `arrays` at the front. So `arrays` becomes shape `(k, m, n)`. Then `arrays>array_ref` will work automagically!

Comment: Also faster, because in C order, the inner loop will be over contigous elements.

Comment: Thank you all! By simply broadcasting ```array_ref[:, :, None]```, I got 0.08 sec/128 aisles, which is 0.25-0.3 seconds ahead of the original for-loop. In terms of storing it to ```(k,m,n)```, somehow ```arrays>array_ref``` significantly slows down the processing (0.5s/128 aisles). Even with ```arrays>array_ref[None,:,:]```, it's still slow. I can't understand or explain why, but I'm observing it...I applied transpose to change the shape, and start the timer after transpose. For now, I prefer the broadcasting method on shape ```(m,k,d)```, at 0.08-0.09 sec/128 aisles.